# Class with map containing function pointers of another class

Tags: c++, function, pointers, pointer-to-member

What I wish to do is have a class that contains a map of function pointers of a second class, but the name of the second class should not matter (cannot be hard coded into the first class) I would really like to be able to implement this WITHOUT using macros. I have followed the examples from learncpp.com on function pointers, but when passing them between classes I am really lost! My attempt is below:

```
#include <map>
class Class1;
typedef double(Class1::*memFunc)();

class Class1
{
  private:

  std::map<std::string, memFunc> funcMap;

  public:

  void addFunc(std::string funcName, memFunc function)
  {
      funcMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, memFunc>(funcName, function));
  }

  };

  class MyClass
  {
  public:

  MyClass()
  {
      //How do I add member function getValue() to Class1?
      class1.addFunc("new function", getValue());
  }

  double getValue()
  {
      return 0;
  }

  private:

  Class1 class1;
  };
```

Comment: As an aside, will you also want to store the object's `this` pointer of the objects to whose member functions you want to store pointers?

Comment: @KerrekSB As it turns out, that is also what I need. I'm sorry I didn't see this reply earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the class is a part of the type of the function pointer, which becomes part of the map's type, which becomes part of MyClass. Depending on how strong is the requirement "cannot be hard coded", perhaps a template would be sufficient?

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
template<typename T>
class Class1
{
    typedef double(T::*memFunc)();
    std::map<std::string, memFunc> funcMap;
 public:
    void addFunc(std::string funcName, memFunc function)
    {
        funcMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, memFunc>(funcName, function));
    }
};

class MyClass
{
 public:
    MyClass()
    {
        class1.addFunc("new function", &MyClass::getValue);
    }
    double getValue()
    {
        return 0;
    }
private:
    Class1<MyClass> class1;
};
int main()
{
     MyClass mc;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I was expecting an answer full of pointers everywhere, structs, and macros and stuff like that. I forget how templates solve so much headache. Thank you so much!

Comment: One more thing, if you don't mind: How would I call a function pointer from MyClass inside Class1? Lets say I retrieve it out of the map:

`double(T::*memFunc)();`
`memFunc = (*mapIterator).second;`
`(this->*memFunc)();`

That does not seem to work.

Comment: @rem45acp if `memFunc` is a function pointer from `MyClass`, it needs an object of type `MyClass` to be called on: https://ideone.com/YAHSG

Comment: Could *this be passed into the template, like so: `Class1<*this>class1`, avoiding the need for the extra parameter?